# Migrating AWS RDS to GCP (sql 5.7)

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, amazon-rds, database-migration

im running mysql 5.7 in my AWS RDS. I wanted to migrate the DB to my GCP without downtime.
How this can be done? Can i create a replica to GCP and use it as Master DB in GCP environement

Comment: Thank John Hanley, will try this guide out

Answer (score 0):

yes, you could create a replicate to external mysql, you could find guideline as below link.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.External.Repl.html

After you switch to gcp, you could still set the replicate the reverse way to aws rds mysql.

Also you could find more detailed steps in below aurora doc link. it contains the configuration for aurora, rds mysql, mysql.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Replication.MySQL.html